# Getting InnerText from XmlDocument throws NullReferenceException

Tags: xml, vb.net

Whenever I try and get the InnerText of an element using an XmlDocument, it throws a NullReferenceException. Here is the code below:

```
    Dim SetDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim xmlString As String = "<upload><links><bananas>apple</bananas><original>thirteen</original></links></upload>"
    SetDoc.LoadXml(xmlString)
    MsgBox(SetDoc.GetElementById("original").InnerText)
```

The same happens when I load exactly the same XML from file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetElementById requires an ID attribute, and also a schema defining the name of the ID attribute.

Use **GetElementsByTagName** instead

```
Msgbox(SetDoc.GetElementsByTagName("original")(0).Innertext)
```

*(I had to put the (0), because GetElementsByTagName returns a list rather than just one item)*

Or you can use the **Item** property

```
Msgbox(SetDoc.Item("upload").Item("links").Item("original").InnerText)
```